# Parse a XES file in Scala

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying since few hours to parse an XES file using the Deckfour XES Open library, I want to have the logs of my file however I can't find any parser which parse my .xes

```
//Getting Xes File
  val logXesFile = request.body.file("file").get
  val filename = logXesFile.filename
  logger.debug(s"filename: $filename")

  //Try all available parsers
  val otherParsers = XParserRegistry.instance().getAvailable
  for(p <- otherParsers){
    try{
      logger.debug(p.name())
      val logs = p.parse(logXesFile.ref.file)
      if(logs.size() > 0){
        logger.debug(s"Parser founded ! $p")
      }
    }
    catch{
      case e : Exception => {logger.debug("Exception !")}
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my debugger : [image: my debugger]

Also I tried plenty of xes files the problem are definitely not from those, I also tried with the GZIP parser

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found !

The "myfile".ref.file allow indeed to get the file however it change the name of the file to something like "multipartBody26...TemporaryFile" and the parser function from the deckfour library do not recognize it as a ".xes" anymore while the content is still an xes file.

So the solution looks to be to rename the file